# Curl : How to pass password containing a percent sign

Tags: php, curl, telnet

I'm not using PHP, but another language for this.. just FYI. However, I included the PHP as a tag, just in case someone there has a solution...

At the moment I'm first trying to get the string right (to download a file through curl from a remote server to a local domain). Anyway, the password contains a percent sign (%).
When I do this, I get the following error on my command line:

```
curl: (67) Access denied: 530
```

The 67 is an error code from curl (see also http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) and means that "The user name, password, or similar was not accepted and curl failed to log in."

Now say the original string would be this:

```
curl -u Login:Pass%Word
```

I've tried the following solutions that I found on the net:

```
curl -u Login:Pass%25Word
curl -u Login:Pass%%Word
curl -u Login:Pass^%Word
curl -u Login:Pass^%%Word
```

However.. I ALWAYS get the Access denied.

Could someone help me out, please?

Comment: Can you try if it works if you change the password? Or if you try a user that has a password without such characters?

Comment: @GolezTrol Good idea. I tried it with a different server, so I would have a different username/pw (without the percent) and it worked, even tho it took 46 seconds to get a file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just replayed your case: made user test / some%password and secured my site.

These two commands works:
`curl -u 'test:some%password'`
`curl -u test:some%password`

It seems you just using wrong password or misspelled server name

Comment: Yes, you're right. I checked the login name that I had in an email, verified it with what I've been using (but never looked at in an ftp connection), and the login name in the email had a capital letter halfway the login. In the ftp (and then I remembered calling about this a few months ago) it did NOT have that capital letter halfway. Fixing this made it all work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it using ASCII code?

```
curl -u Login:Pass%25Word
```

[Source](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2007-10/0150.html)

Comment: (and I got the other things I tried also from that website... )